How to access metadata of Named Fields in a RecordType using Dart Analyzer?
I am working on a Dart builder and need to inspect the metadata (annotations) applied to the named fields of a RecordType. However, while I can successfully access RecordType.namedFields, the resulting RecordTypeNamedField objects do not appear to expose any metadata-related members.
Here is an example of the code I am trying to analyze:
Future<({@SomeAnnotation() String foo, int bar})?> someFunction() async {
  return null;
}

In this case, I need to determine programmatically that the foo field is annotated with @SomeAnnotation.
My Setup:
Dart SDK: 3.6.0
Analyzer version: 6.11.0
Question:
How can I access the metadata (annotations) of a named field in a RecordType using Dart's analyzer package in the context of a builder? Is there a specific API or workaround to achieve this?

It seems like you specifically asked the question in such a way that no one but you could understand it.

@mezoni sorry. I have edited it. Is it better now?
